# comparison of a continuous distribution with a discrete one

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I am trying to compare the closeness of a continuous distribution with a discrete one. Clearly KL doesn't work because they have different support. I have searched online, there is Levy-Prokhorov metric which can do the job, but it is a bit complicated to compute. Is there any simpler measure of distance between a continuous distribution and a discrete distribution?

Comment: You could try the [earth mover's distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance)

Comment: Otherwise, can't you discretize (area between $n-1/2$ and $n+1/2$) the continuous function, and compare discrete-to-discrete ?

Comment: @Gcab Problems: 1. What if the discrete distribution is not integer valued? 2. Consider the uniform distribution on (1/2,3/2) vs. a constant distribution at 1. Your technique would say they are 0 distance apart.

Comment: If I discretize I still run into the problem of not having the same support.

Comment: @Ian, evidently I do not get what "to compare the closeness .." actually means in this context: could you please clarify for "non-specialists" ? I am just curious to learn (I have an engineering knowledge of probability/statistics).

Comment: @RZL, same comment as above

Comment: Various goodness-of-fit statistics (some comparing ECDF of data) to continuous CDF) have various solutions. Maybe start by looking at Kolmogorov-Smirnov. As I recall, one of these uses the metric in @Henry's Answer.

Comment: @GCab You want to put a metric $M$ on the set of all probability distributions on $\mathbb{R}$ or perhaps some subset thereof. The one property that $M$ must naturally have is that convergence in $M$ should imply convergence in distribution. One would like convergence in $M$ to be either equivalent to convergence in distribution or perhaps slightly stronger, but not drastically stronger. Your example is not even a metric, because it does not distinguish between the uniform distribution on a set symmetric about an integer and the distribution which is concentrated on that integer.

Comment: @Ian, thanks a lot, I got it (almost..). So, from the whole of the statements herewith, I understand that the procedure is on the reverse: you transform the discrete one into continuous stepwise (histogram) and apply a metric for continuous functions, is that right ? on the density or  on the cumulative ?

Comment: No, you don't really want to do any conversion in general. You want your metric to work directly on the original measures. The Wasserstein metric for example does actually do this.

Comment: @GCab You can also think about it as a metric on CDFs instead of a metric on measures, it is the same. But you won't have densities, at least not in the classical sense. (Of course you do have densities in the sense of distribution theory, but that's more complicated than just working with measure theory in the first place.)

Answer (score 1):

In comments I suggested the [earth mover's distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance), apparently also called the Wasserstein metric or Mallows distance

Given two distributions on $\mathbb{R}$ with cumulative distribution functions $F(x)$ and $G(x)$, I believe this can be stated as $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left|F(x)-G(x)\right|\, dx$

As a simple example, compare the uniform discrete distribution on $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$ with the uniform continuous distribution on $\left[0,n\right]$: you get a value of $\frac12$