# Quantizing a real-valued random variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables, hermite-polynomials

Let us consider that we are given a real-valued random variable $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ with a continuous probability density function under a given probability measure. I am looking for references that would tell me how to construct a *discrete random variable* $Y$ such that the cumulative density functions of $Y$ and $X$ are close. One problem seems to be how to select the set of values that $Y$ can take, and an additional problem seems to be how to select the probabilities over these points.

Another question that bothers me is: how to define closeness between $X$ and $Y$ (its discrete counterpart)?

I am thinking that there must be some standard text (possibly even undergraduate level) that deals with these questions, but have found none yet. I would be really grateful if you could point to an authoritative reference that covers this topic.

Comment: I'd ask this on https://stats.stackexchange.com , and add a reference request tag. Just binning is my naive idea. The maximum difference between the CDFs is easy to determine based on the number of bins. As for measuring the distance between distributions, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1888370/comparison-of-a-continuous-distribution-with-a-discrete-one or https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194772/statistical-distance-between-discrete-and-continuous-distributions